# is it possible to automatically repeat a request every 3 sec in advanced-rest client

Tags: json, api, rest, post, advanced-rest-client

I'm trying to **repeat** my POST request every 3 sec. Anybody an idea how I can do this in *advanced-rest client*? I can't find it on internet.

Answer (score 0):

ARC doesn't have this feature, unfortunately. No one asked me for this ever before. The project is in maintenance mode, and currently, I am not planning to introduce new features. However, you can add a feature request to ARC's repository (https://github.com/advanced-rest-client/arc-electron/issues) so future maintainers may consider adding it.